# Android NDK __system_property_find failling sometimes

Tags: android

I am using the __system_property_find function in native android (NDK) to retrieve values such as ro.build.fingerprint (I don't want to get them through Java for security reasons).
It does work fine altough "some times" the function return false while it should find the property:
- on the same mobile phone, I got it working, then not working then working when running the app 3 times consecutively
- calling this function several times in the same execution either always work or always fails
- no changes in privileges
- it's hardly reproductible (automatically launching / killing the app several hundred times did not reproduce the bug)
- but on thousands of installations I've got at least ten mobiles having the problem.

```
const prop_info *pi;
pi = __system_property_find("ro.serialno");
if (pi == 0) {
// We've got a problem
}
```

Any idea of what could go wrong with this function?

Many thanks

Comment: `__system_property_get` works the same way?

Comment: we do not know, we do not use this function
it is a behaviour that we statically see on some of our clients' mobiles and we are not able to reproduce it today in our labs.
It may depend on device, os, other app installed, configuration or something else ... we do not have a clue today as we cannot reproduce in lab.

Answer (score 0):

__system_property_find() and __system_property_get() are become hidden in the 64-bit toolchains since ANDROID API 21.

Try to use below method to get instead.

```
File *file = popen("getprop ro.serialno", "r"); 
fread(pi, 1, PROP_VALUE_MAX, file);
pclose(file);
```